# Angular CLI - different sets of dev and prod assets

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I can't seem to find if and how it would be possible to use a different set of assets whenever I use the `--prod` switch of `ng build`.

The use case is that I have multiple projects with a common set of assets in a shared folder, so the configuration of each single project in angular.json is like this:

```
"assets": [
  {
    "glob": "**/*",
    "input": "src/assets",
    "output": "/assets/"
  },
  {
    "glob": "**/*",
    "input": "projects/project1/src/assets/",
    "output": "/assets/"
  }
],
...
"assets": [
  {
    "glob": "**/*",
    "input": "src/assets",
    "output": "/assets/"
  },
  {
    "glob": "**/*",
    "input": "projects/project2/src/assets/",
    "output": "/assets/"
  }
],
```

When making production builds, I would like to remove the common `src/assets` path.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer was right under my nose: each `configurations` object allows a redefined `assets` property.

So my requirement's configuration is as simple as:

```
{
"configurations": {
  "production": {
     "assets": [
       {
         "glob": "**/*",
         "input": "projects/project1/src/assets/",
         "output": "/assets/"
       }
     ],
     ...
  }
}
```

It works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You need check for setting up configuration. This configuration will help you to create different environment for your project. In your case project 2.

you need to set different environment on the angular.json

```
"project2": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "", //project 1 folder
              "with": "" // project 2 folder
            },
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ]
        }
```

after setup you can hit command

```
ng build --configuration project2
```

Note: you need to set necessary parameter in new environment like below

```
"optimization": true,
"outputHashing": "all",
"sourceMap": false,
"extractCss": true,
"namedChunks": false,
"aot": true,
"extractLicenses": true,
"vendorChunk": false,
"buildOptimizer": true,
```

Detail official documentation link https://angular.io/guide/build

Comment: how can i replace index.html for development and production ?